# Adjusting the height of math floor symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions, delimiters

Recently I started to play with LaTeX again just to train for when I have to use it again.
I like to write mathematical formulas and I am trying to nail down floor and ceil symbols with fractions.
However the results I get are kind of weird, in my opinion. Example code below:

```
    $\left\lfloor\dfrac{2}{3}\right\rfloor$
    $\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{n}\right\rfloor$ 
    $\left\lfloor\dfrac{A}{n}\right\rfloor$
    $\left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{N}\right\rfloor$
```

This code generates this output (compiling with PDFLaTeX):

[image]

The height of the floor symbol is inconsistent, it is smaller when the fraction contains a lowercase letter in the numerator and larger when the fraction contains numbers or uppercase letters in the numerator.
Why is that the case? How can I produce floor symbols that are always the larger size shown in the picture?

Comment: better use `\bigl` and `\bigr` rather than `\left` to get consistent size, or use `\strut` in all cases eg `\dfrac{\strut a}{\strut n}` so your fractions are the same size.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It would be nice if some struts where there [by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnwLw.png). Or at least via a setup. Maybe something to take up?

Comment: @mickep I suppose you are going to tell me that some other format does this better?

Comment: `\bigl` and `\bigr` did not work here... `\strut` kind of worked but it made the floor signs a little bit too high

Comment: by `\bigl` I meant choose a suitable size (`\biggl` or whatever you need) note the accepted answer is a primitive tex construct that should never be used in latex (and will generate warnings if used with amsmath)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX uses a discrete set of five bracket sizes (not counting the massive brackets around matrices, etc.). Using `\left` and `\right` invokes an algorithm that calculates which to use, based on what appears inside. Sometimes this algorithm results in a choice that is not visually appealing.

If you want to create a sequence of objects contained in brackets of the same size, it's simplest to choose the size yourself, using `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl` or `\Biggl` along with the associated commands ending in `r`. Another option is to influence `\left` and `\right` by inserting vertical rules (struts). Note that the optional argument to `\rule` is used to move it up and down, whereas the mandatory arguments are the width followed by the height. You can change the width to 0pt once you are happy with the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\biggl\lfloor\dfrac{2}{3}\biggr\rfloor$
$\biggl\lfloor\dfrac{a}{n}\biggr\rfloor$
$\biggl\lfloor\dfrac{A}{n}\biggr\rfloor$
$\biggl\lfloor\dfrac{a}{N}\biggr\rfloor$

\bigskip

$\left\lfloor\rule[-8pt]{1pt}{20pt}\dfrac{2}{3}\right\rfloor$
$\left\lfloor\rule[-8pt]{1pt}{20pt}\dfrac{a}{n}\right\rfloor$
$\left\lfloor\rule[-8pt]{1pt}{20pt}\dfrac{A}{n}\right\rfloor$
$\left\lfloor\rule[-8pt]{1pt}{20pt}\dfrac{a}{N}\right\rfloor$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\overwithdelims` TeX primitive:

```
\let\ds=\displaystyle
$\ds {2\overwithdelims\lfloor\rfloor 3}$
$\ds {a\overwithdelims\lfloor\rfloor n}$
$\ds {A\overwithdelims\lfloor\rfloor n}$
$\ds {a\overwithdelims\lfloor\rfloor N}$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en) package to create your own `\floor` command that lets you freely choose between inferred and manually-specified delimiter sizes:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
```

Use `\floor` as `\floor*{...}` for interfered delimiter sizes or as `\floor[\SIZE]{...}` for `\SIZE`-sized delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries Inferred:}]
    \item[Inferred:]
    $\floor*{\dfrac{2}{3}}$
    $\floor*{\dfrac{a}{n}}$ 
    $\floor*{\dfrac{A}{n}}$
    $\floor*{\dfrac{a}{N}}$

    \item [\texttt{\textbackslash{}big}:]
    $\floor[\big]{\dfrac{2}{3}}$
    $\floor[\big]{\dfrac{a}{n}}$ 
    $\floor[\big]{\dfrac{A}{n}}$
    $\floor[\big]{\dfrac{a}{N}}$
    
    \item [\texttt{\textbackslash{}Big}:]
    $\floor[\Big]{\dfrac{2}{3}}$
    $\floor[\Big]{\dfrac{a}{n}}$ 
    $\floor[\Big]{\dfrac{A}{n}}$
    $\floor[\Big]{\dfrac{a}{N}}$
    
    \item [\texttt{\textbackslash{}bigg}:]
    $\floor[\bigg]{\dfrac{2}{3}}$
    $\floor[\bigg]{\dfrac{a}{n}}$ 
    $\floor[\bigg]{\dfrac{A}{n}}$
    $\floor[\bigg]{\dfrac{a}{N}}$
    
    \item [\texttt{\textbackslash{}Bigg}:]
    $\floor[\Bigg]{\dfrac{2}{3}}$
    $\floor[\Bigg]{\dfrac{a}{n}}$ 
    $\floor[\Bigg]{\dfrac{A}{n}}$
    $\floor[\Bigg]{\dfrac{a}{N}}$
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: \floor with various delimiter sizes]